# Decoding makefile flags for beginners

Tags: makefile

Can someone let me know what these two flags do in this makefile?  I've googled 'till my fingures hurt, but cannot find any info.  The GNU documentation doesn't seem have this info.
Thanks!

(-ln) and (-fs)

```
$(MAKE) -C wiringPi $@
$(MAKE) -C devLib $@
-ln -fs libwiringPiDev.so.2.0 devLib/libwiringPiDev.so
-ln -fs libwiringPi.so.2.0 wiringPi/libwiringPi.so
$(MAKE) -C gpio 'INCLUDE=-I../devLib -I../wiringPi' 'LDFLAGS=-L../devLib -L../wiringPi' $@
```

Comment: These look like commands, not flags. Dunno why prepended with `-`, though..

Comment: OK.  So where would one look up what these are?  I'm assuming they are makefile specific. I just don't know, but would like to learn.

Comment: The leading **`-`** tells `make` to ignore any error (though often `make` ignores that, and stops on an error).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be based on a fortuitous misunderstanding. It is unlikely to be of use to future readers, and I do not see how it can be made so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ln -fs foo bar` command creates a link named `bar` pointing to file `foo`. The `-f` option forces the creation: if a `bar` already exists it is overwritten (except if it is a directory). The `-s` option tells `ln` to create a symbolic link instead of the default hard link. See `man ln` to know more about this command.

The `-` on front of the command tells make that it should not abort if the command fails. If you are using GNU make see the [make manual section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors) about errors in recipes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eugene.  Without the '-' I was able to find more info.

So I think the ln with the (-fs) is checking, then removing a existing file (if there is one) then making a symbolic link. cool.

I'm sure this was / is obvious to the experienced out there.

Thanks,
oc.